# MultiBinding not working in DataGridTextColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I am trying to use a MultiBinding to update a DataGridTextColumn.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFBench.MultiBindingProblem"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFBench"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MultiBindingProblem" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MultiValueConverter x:Key="MultiValueConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding TableA}" ColumnWidth="100*">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="MultiValue">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Value"/>
                        <Binding Path="Value"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

Here is the converter...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WPFBench
{
   public class MultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
   {
       public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           return values[0];
       }

       public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
}
```

The code behind...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WPFBench
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MultiBindingProblem.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MultiBindingProblem : Window
{
    DataTable _tableA = new DataTable();
    public MultiBindingProblem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _tableA.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(double)));
        _tableA.Rows.Add(0.0);
        _tableA.Rows.Add(1.0);
        _tableA.Rows.Add(2.0);
        _tableA.Rows.Add(3.0);
        _tableA.Rows.Add(4.0);
        DataContext = this;
    }
    public DataTable TableA
    {
        get { return _tableA; }
    }
}
}
```

The single binding column is updated.  The multivalue converter is called.  The multivalue column remains blank.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you binding all to the same thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `Value` is a value type like an `int` and not a `string`, this issue happens because there is **no implicit conversion from object to string**.

Try returning a

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return String.Format("{0}", values[0]);  // don't return an object values[0];
}
```

from the `Convert` method.

Also put a breakpoint and check if `values` is correctly filled as expected.

Simple demo to **prove** that this is the **correct** answer.

Start you window in the question from a button of the main window

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MultiBindingProblem probl = new MultiBindingProblem();
    probl.DataContext = new DemoRoughViewModel();
    probl.Show();
}
```

using a simple, rough view model

```
public class DemoRoughTable
{
    public int Value { get; set; }  // Notice that it's not a string
}
public class DemoRoughViewModel
{
    public List<DemoRoughTable> TableA { get; set; } = new List<DemoRoughTable>()
    {
        new DemoRoughTable() { Value = 1 }, new DemoRoughTable() { Value = 2 }
    };
}
```

**HTH**

Comment: If you have any doubts, please comment down here and let me know.

Comment: Indeed, I added value[0].ToString() and everything started working.  The value array contains doubles.  The single binding has an implicit conversion to string apparently but not the multi-binding.  This seems wrong.

Comment: I understand your comparison and what you mean, but I would reply in this way: the difference is not between single and multi-binding, but between either using a converter or not: it is the `Convert` method that introduce the cast to `object`, not the binding type.

Answer (score 1):

Your example should work, as long as you convert `values[0]` to its `string` representation in the `Convert` method of `IMultiValueConverter` (As explained by other answers here). However, your example here is a little strange, because there is no need for a `MultiBinding`. (I know you are aware of them, since the first column demonstrates a more proper approach).

Anyway, I think  you need a `MultiBinding` for the `Binding` property of a `DataGridTextColumn`, when you want to set the `Binding` dynamically. In this case, you should send the `DataContext` and the path string, and retrieve its value in a `IMultiValueConverter`. There is [an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42388849/5615980), similar to this situation, in which the `Binding` changes based on the value in the header of the `DataGridTextColumn`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Of course the example is strange...I simplified it greatly from the actual code so I could present the problem properly here.

What I am trying to do with the multi-binding is to combine two columns into one to save space.  One column is a double and one column is a string.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

The `Binding` property of a `DataGridTextColumn` is supposed to be set to a `BindingBase` object and not to a data bound *value*.

If you intend to show a value returned by the converter in the column you should use a `DataGridTemplateColumn`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MultiValue">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Value"/>
                        <Binding Path="Value"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Also make sure that you are returning a string from the converter:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return values[0].ToString();
}
```